# Isabelle - Nitpick - using witness values automatically

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

How can I automatically use the values found by `nitpick`, instead of using `rule exI`'s and manually typing in the witness values?

```
  theorem "EX a b. a + b = 5 & a - b = (1 :: int)"
    nitpick [falsify=false]

    (* Nitpicking formula... 
       Nitpick found a model:

       Skolem constants:
       a = 3
       b = 2
    *)

    apply (rule exI[where x="3"])
    apply (rule exI[where x="2"])
    apply (simp)
  done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that functionality exists, since I'd say this is not a typical use case.

One could probably add something like this to the `nitpick` command with a relatively small amount of effort or create a new command to do it.